# requestPermission does not return after authorization in edge only

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, promise, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to create a project utilizing googles firebase from the sample code, after integration the promise, edge never returns the answer to javascript.

```
messages.requestPermission().then(function () {
console.log('Notification permission granted.');
```

console.log is never hit from within edge, works fine on all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

From https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api it looks like Edge does not support **W3C Push API**.